# cocos 2d-x js sheet animation do not work

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

I add a sprite that has eventListener to layer.When I touch it no error but no effect yet.

Here is my code:

```js
onTouchBegan : function (event) {
                var spriteFrames = [];
                var frame = cc.spriteFrameCache.getSpriteFrame(res.stone_png);
                var frame1 = cc.spriteFrameCache.getSpriteFrame(res.cloth_png);
                spriteFrames.push(frame);
                spriteFrames.push(frame1);
                var animation = new cc.Animation(spriteFrames, 2, 30);
                var action = cc.animate(animation);
                action.retain();
                clickSprite.runAction(
                    action
                );
            }
```

I make sure eventListener is no problem.Thanks for helps.Apologize for my English.